# Python Arabic string contatenated with number

Tags: python, arabic, right-to-left

With Python 2.7.11, I am trying to build a string with Arabic characters and a number. But, the number always ends up on the left side of the final string instead of the right. Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python  -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

city = 'الدوحة'
street = 'شارع بابل'
number = '6990'

address = city + ' ' + street + ' ' + number
print address

address = number + ' ' + city + ' ' + street + ' '
print address
```

And the output, from Aptana:

```
الدوحة شارع بابل 6990
6990 الدوحة شارع بابل
```

What can I do to force the number to the right of the final string?

**UPDATE**
Turns out, from the command line, the output is as expected, but, from Apatana Studio, the console is reformatting the string. Arabic is tricky to work with using English tools.

That said, I think the string is correct. But, I am next inserting into MySQL and then displaying on a web page, where it is wrong. So, not sure if the insert is re-formatting it, or, if it is being rendered incorrectly by HTML.

Comment: reverse the makeup of `address`....`address = number + ' ' +city +' '+ street`

Comment: isnt't that output correct in arabic context? if we start to read from right to left doesn't it seems ok?

Comment: Reversing the order makes no difference. About to update the post. Reading from right to left, I expect house number, street and then city (as in the US). That is, "City Street House-Number". Correct me if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with Aptana, it doesn't know anything about right-to-left and displays everything left-to-right, as you have seen.

On the web page, set the page's direction to right-to-left, or at least the element where you display the Arabic strings.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to set an HTML element left to right? Or, can I use the Unicode Left to Right marker?

Comment: Interestingly, the css markup had not effect in Chrome. Instead, I put the HTML markup "&rlm;" at the beginning of the string. So, I am now building the string as I would a western String, except adding the markup: "&rlm;House number + Street + City", and the string is rendered correctly.